Which characters are supposed to be italic in an italic font?
I've been looking at a few italic fonts on my system and while letters and numbers are always slanted, certain symbols often seem to be skipped. Some examples include the vertical bar (|), the underscore (_), tilde (~), plus sign (+) and caret (^). Apart from maybe a minor shift in position, these are often identical to their Roman counterparts. Is there a reason for this? Are there guidelines for what SHOULD be italicised by font designers when creating an italic font?

How does this show for you? abc|def/ source: *abc|def/* I see everything italicised here, but copy/paste to a text document I get a vertical pipe. Helvetica Neue italic.

Sorry, @Tetsujin, I don't understand. The question is about guidelines. I can see the italic vertical bar as upright in the comments on Stack Exchange. I need to know which characters I should be designing this way. @cybernetic.nomad I had thought this too, but I can't explain the other symbols. One theory I read said that in typesetting, mathematical symbols were originally a distinct set from any font used, and so would not be italicised when a font was changed. However, that does not explain the asterisk (*) often also not being italicised.
